# How do I extract <input> tags from and (X)HTML input in PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex, tags, extract

I need to extract all the  tags from an HTML file, In such a way that I would end up with either an array containing key=value for each of the attributes, or at least the raw text that makes up the tag.

I don't quite get along with regex, much less in PHP, so I would really appreciate some help in this.

PD: Some of the  tags may span several lines and be indented with tabs and spaces on the subsequent lines.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is the [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DOM functions](https://www.php.net/book.dom) to parse an XML/XHTML document into a DOM Tree. From there it's not too hard to traverse the nodes you wish, extracting the data you're looking for.

Some people prefer the [SimpleXML functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) which might work equally well for you. I personally have issues with SimpleXML and prefer the more verbose, but more powerful DOM functions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its easy. Use the DOM-Function of PHP and try to find the nodes with XPath.
That should be the painless way.